# How to get ng-dirty class applied to every input on external model change?

Tags: angularjs

I need to turn the background colour of each input to green by clicking the button:

http://jsfiddle.net/coma/jst7cfgb/

**Logic**

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {

    $rootScope.change = function () {

        $rootScope.data = {
            email: 'foo@foo.coo',
            name : 'foo'
        };
    };
});
```

**View**

```
<button ng-click="change()">Paint them green!</button>

<form name="form">
    <input type="email" ng-model="data.email"/>
    <input type="name" ng-model="data.name"/>
</form>
```

**Style**

```
input.ng-dirty {
    background-color: #53ed9a;
}
```

**Notes**

- This is just an example, don't ask for controllers or reasons.
- If this is a duplicated one, mark it as it and link to the original one, I'll delete it.
- If you really really want to downvote, explain why at least and be sure that I'll delete the question after.
- Angular 1.3.

Comment: `I need to turn the background colour of each input to green by clicking the button:` --> Shouldn't be hard, i guess. Just a small css rule, and ng-class. http://plnkr.co/edit/r0YkFx?p=preview. `<form name="form" ng-class="{'submitted':submitted}">` and `form.submitted input,input.ng-dirty {...`

Comment: @PSL, thanks! but no, what I want is to get the ng-dirty class applied on every input just like when you change the model by hand.

Comment: Thats not what you wrote in your question. But when you type it will already turn green no, based on your current rule? Or is this what you are looking for? http://plnkr.co/edit/r0YkFx?p=preview Sorry i cannot access fiddle so posted based on your stuff

Comment: Try to use $setViewValue http://jsfiddle.net/mkhefvq4/

Comment: @PSL, title updated. The thing is that I'm not sure if there is a way to set them as dirty since the model has changed externally. I know that the one getting "dirty" is the form field itself, not the model, but I just wanted to be sure if there is a way.

Comment: @originof, thanks!, this is exactly was I have implemented right now but I need to crawl the data object in order to trigger it on every field and I was wondering if there is another way of propagating it from the parent form to its children.

Comment: You can make dirty all the form with $rootScope.myForm.$setDirty()

Comment: @originof, "This method will also propagate to parent forms." https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController#$setDirty , check it: http://jsfiddle.net/coma/jst7cfgb/1/

Comment: Yes if your form is inside another form the parent form become dirty.
http://jsfiddle.net/a9azy4wk/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62614/discussion-between-originof-and-coma).